# Get item from array based on parameter

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

I have an array of objects. The constructor is

```
Planet : function(planet)
{
    this.name = planet.name;
    this.percComp = planet.percComp;
    this.preReq = planet.preReq;
}
```

Is there a way using jquery or underscore to get an object or objects, out of the array based on the objects parameter.

Something like

```
_getItem(planetArray, Planet.name === 'Mars')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try Underscore's `where` method

```
_.where(listOfPlanets, {name: "Mars"});
```

Say you have the following list of planets -  `prop` is a made up property

```
var listOfPlanets = [
    { name: 'Mercury', prop:1},
    { name: 'Venus', prop:2},
    { name: 'Earth', prop:3},
    { name: 'Mars', prop:4},
    { name: 'Jupiter', prop:5},
    { name: 'Saturn', prop:6},
    { name: 'Uranus', prop:7},
    { name: 'Neptune', prop:8} ];
```

To get the Mars object just do the following. Keep in mind that `_.where` returns an array of matches. Accessing the index `0` or using `_.first` will be needed

```
var mars = _.where(listOfPlanets, {name: "Mars"})[0];
console.log(mars.prop);    // 4
```

Underscore also has a `_.find` method, which can be used to retrieve only the first match

```
var mars = _.find(listOfPlanets, function(p){ return p.name === 'Mars' });
console.log(mars.prop);    // 4
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/6bxnK/1/

Answer (score 2):

This is what jQuery's [`grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) method is for:

```
var theObject = $.grep(planetArray, function (el) {
    return el.name === 'mars';
})[0];
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g7syV/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/):

```
 $.grep(arr, function (obj) { return obj.name === 'Mars'; });
```

This will return an array of objects that meet the criteria.